# Checking Internet Connection in SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode, networking, connection, monitor

what’s the easiest way to check internet connection?

I found this code example but is the most efficient way in Xcode11/Swift5?

I only need to check for connection under a button press before calling my function which downloads from the internet. So a simple check before calling my function will do it. Is this constant monitoring the most efficient? Or should I use something directly under my button press.

```
import Network

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "InternetConnectionMonitor")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { pathUpdateHandler in
        if pathUpdateHandler.status == .satisfied {
            print("Internet connection is on.")
        } else {
            print("There's no internet connection.")
        }
    }

    monitor.start(queue: queue)
}

}
```

Comment: Aside from the duplicate, I'd like to remind you there's always a chance there's a connection right *before* the user press the button, but it's lost when you actually try to download something. Since your download code already handle the sudden connection loss scenario, I don't see why you need to add redundant & unreliable check before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used for this the Reachability framework by ashleymills:
https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

You just need to import via:
`import ReachabilitySwift`

Then just inside your view controller you can do e.g.:

```
let reachability = try! Reachability()

if reachability.isReachable {
   print("Internet connection is on.")
}
```

See the ReadMe of the repo for more examples on how to use the closures.
Beware that it is an external framework and might not be up to date with the latest Swift version.

Answer (score 0):

import SystemConfiguration:

```
import SystemConfiguration
```

before the viewController class add this class:

```
public class Reachability {

class func isConnected() -> Bool {

    var noAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    noAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: noAddress))
    noAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &noAddress) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {noSockAddress in
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, noSockAddress)
        }
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
    let ret = (isReachable && !needsConnection)

    return ret
}
}
```

Now in viewDidLoad check the connection:

```
if Reachability.isConnected(){
        print("Internet Connection is ON")
    } else {
        print("Internet Connection OFF")
    }
```